# Nginx: Password Protect directory index but display subroute

Tags: nginx, password-protection, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have the following directory structure:

```
/home
/home/static
/home/static/image1.png
/home/static/pdf1.pdf
```

I a want to password protect the access for `www.mypage.com/uploads` and visualize the index of the files currently in that directory but if someone goes to `www.mypage.com/uploads/pdf1.pdf`, the request should not be authenticated and display the file without asking for password.

So far I have the following nginx configuration which asks me for user and password on the `/uploads` path as well as `/uploads/pdf1.pdf`.

**Nginx config**

```
location /uploads {
  alias /home/static/;
  autoindex on;
  auth_basic "Private Route";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
}
```

**[EDIT] Proposed working solution:**

```sh
location ~/uploads$ {
  alias /home/static/;
  autoindex on;
  auth_basic "Private Route";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
}
location /uploads {
  alias /home/static/;
  autoindex off;
  auth_basic off;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions:

```
location /uploads {
    alias /home/static; # no trailing slash here!
    location = /uploads/ {
        autoindex on;
        auth_basic "Private Route";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for the response. 
I ended up implementing another solution. Yours look cleaner though.

Comment: @renanz Solution you added with the edit is unworkable. It will give you HTTP 403 Forbidden (request `/uploads` will be redirected to `/uploads/` where autoindex is disabled). Moreover, your `/uploads$` regex pattern will match any string that ends with `/uploads` (e.g. `/some/path/uploads`, `/second/path/uploads` etc.). And moreover, using regex matching is an extra performance impact and should be avoided whenever possible.